# Dependency version conflict on Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage in WorkerRole that also depends on Microsoft.Hadoop.Client

Tags: .net, azure, hadoop, storage, conflict

This seems like a newbie problem, but I've been digging and searching for hours, and could use a little help.

I have a Worker Role in my cloud service that has a dependency tree that looks something like this (nuget is used to manage the microsoft assembly references, and the references to my own assemblies are project references):

```
 MyWorkerRole

      Depends on MyStorageLibrary

           Depends on Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage v4.3.0.0

      Depends on MyBigDataLibrary

           Depends on Microsoft.Hadoop.Client v1.5.8.0

               Depends on Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage v3.0.3.0 or better

           Depends on Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage v4.3.0.0 (my code in this library doesn't use it directly - this is pulled in by nuget when adding the reference to the hadoop client)
```

I also have a Unit Test project, MyBigDataLibrary.Test with an identical reference structure.

Both the unit test (more of an integration test, really) and the worker role do the following: use MyStorageLibrary to test some blobs to see if some action needs to be performed, then uses MyBigDataLibrary to run a Hive job, which ultimately calls GetJobOutput() on the JobSubmissionClient (which I assume is using the storage library under the hood to access the output file in blob storage).

My unit test works fine, returning a stream.

When I run my Worker Role in my local compute emulator, the Hive job runs, but right as it completes and it tries to return the result stream I am getting:

```
 System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Hadoop.Client.Storage.WabStorageAbstraction.Read(Uri path)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.JobSubmission.HDInsightHadoopClient.<GetJobResultFile>d__3d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.JobSubmission.HDInsightHadoopClient.<GetJobOutputAsync>d__22.MoveNext()

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.Framework.Core.Library.TaskExtensions.WaitForResult[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.Framework.Core.Library.TaskExtensions.WaitForResult[T](Task`1 task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.JobSubmission.HDInsightHadoopClient.GetJobOutput(String jobId)
   at MyBigDataLibrary.HDInsight.Hadoop.HiveCommand.ExecuteGetStream() in c:\Development\C#\RetailDataImport.CloudServices\trunk\PremierConcepts.Arch.BigData\HDInsight\Hadoop\HiveCommand.cs:line 61
```

The following does appear in MyWorkerRole.dll.config:

```
   <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldDataVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newDataVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I know that both the unit test and the worker role are successfully loading Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 4.3.0.0 because both are successfully accessing blobs in storage prior to attempting to run the Hive job, and I have used Process Explorer to view the loaded assemblies.

I am in the process of deploying to a test Cloud Service instance to find out if it has the same problem in Azure proper, and can report back on that result, but it is taking some time, and I need to solve the problem in the emulator either way.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: As a followup - my Worker Role does not appear to have this problem when running in Azure proper.

Comment: I was looking at the wrong logs - it in fact DOES have the same problem when running in Azure proper.

Comment: I did check out the post below - the log referenced a copy of the application configuration file that did contain the bindingRedirect above, and the publicKeyToken matched that of the assembly that ended up in my bin folder.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx